# How to properly display div content when click users randomly in React

Tags: reactjs

The code below successfully display users div messages at the bottom of the page when clicked Users button serially **(Eg User1, User2, user3 etc.)**

[image: Screenshot_Serial]

Here is my issue: when I click the Users Button randomly **(Eg. User1, user6, user5, user12 etc.)** The div message  box gets scattered all over the page as can be seen in the screenshot below.

I do not know if the issue is from CSS or React components.

How do I get each of the user's message div to be displayed correctly at the bottom whether the users button is clicked serially or randomly?

[image: screenshot_randomly]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
.mainArea {
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  bottom: 0%
}
.contact_box {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 250px;
  background: black;
  color: red;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block; 
}
</style>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.state = {
      arr: [
    { id: 1,     name: "user1"},
    { id: 2,     name: "user2"},
    { id: 3,     name: "user3"},
    { id: 4,     name: "user4"},
    { id: 5,     name: "user5"},
    { id: 6,     name: "user6"},
    { id: 7,     name: "user7"},
    { id: 8,     name: "user8"},
    { id: 9,     name: "user9"},
    { id: 10,    name: "user10"},
    { id: 11,    name: "user11"},
    { id: 12,    name: "user12"},
    { id: 13,    name: "user13"},
    { id: 14,    name: "user14"},
    { id: 15,    name: "user15"}
      ],
popStatus: false,

    };
   this.popIt = this.popIt.bind(this);
  }

  popIt(id) {
   
this.state.arr[id].popStatus = true;
this.setState({
          popStatus: true
        });
     }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h3>List of users Records</h3>
<div class="sidebar">
          <ul>
            {this.state.arr.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.name} - {obj.name}
 <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => { this.popIt(i); }}
                  className=""
                >
                 {obj.name}
                </button>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
      </div>
<div className="mainArea">
            {this.state.arr.map((obj, i) => (
              <div  key={i} className="contact_box" >
{obj.popStatus === true && <div className="">
        <b>Username:</b> {obj.name}<br />
          Message .........<br />
          Message .........<br />
          Message .........<br />
          Message .........<br />
          Message .........<br />
          Message .........<br />
</div> 
   } 
</div> 
 ))}
</div>
</div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to use a different value for the key prop. Index is not a reliable value for the key. My favorite article on why: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop

Comment: @esinator if I use obj.id as the key props, it does not work hence the same issue persist. Please do you still have any other solution

Comment: Let me know if my updated example in the answer below is helpful. I think maybe you can explain a little what you're hoping to do with `popIt` and `popStatus` but hopefully the example helps.

Comment: The reason the issue persists is covered in the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is partly the result of your CSS and partly the result of your conditional rendering logic in your JSX.

### CSS

You have a styled wrapper that displays for every user regardless of whether `popStatus` is true. That styled wrapper has a fixed width so it takes up space on the page whether or not anything actually renders inside of it.

More specifically, you’re rendering this div for every user:

```
<div  key={i} className="contact_box" >
```

Take a look at where this line sits in your JSX.

The column gaps you see between user info boxes are these `div` being rendered. You can use whatever CSS you want just keep in mind if you include an element wrapping your conditional check for `popStatus` in your render then it will show for each user.

The most straightforward solution is to just remove it or move it down inside the render after your conditional check.

### Conditional Rendering

When you map over users you can perform your conditional check for `popStatus` ***first***.

This way, you will only render something when the condition is met.

Also better to set the `key` to be the user `id` to uniquely identify the user rather than use an index.

NOTE: You should avoid mutating state directly. This line: `this.state.arr[id].popStatus = true;` should be moved inside `setState` and you should return a new copy when performing this update.

NOTE: It's unclear what the `popStatus` prop on the top level object in your state is doing as it seems irrelevant to your problem. I commented it out from the demo.

The demo below should get you going in the right direction I think.

### Example/Demo (View at the link below)

https://codesandbox.io/s/user-list-pop-example-vuyx59

**styles.css**

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-area {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 8px;
}

.contact-box {
  background: black;
  color: red;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

const initialState = {
  users: [
    { id: 1, name: "user1", popStatus: false },
    { id: 2, name: "user2", popStatus: false },
    { id: 3, name: "user3", popStatus: false },
    { id: 4, name: "user4", popStatus: false },
    { id: 5, name: "user5", popStatus: false },
    { id: 6, name: "user6", popStatus: false },
    { id: 7, name: "user7", popStatus: false },
    { id: 8, name: "user8", popStatus: false },
    { id: 9, name: "user9", popStatus: false },
    { id: 10, name: "user10", popStatus: false },
    { id: 11, name: "user11", popStatus: false },
    { id: 12, name: "user12", popStatus: false },
    { id: 13, name: "user13", popStatus: false },
    { id: 14, name: "user14", popStatus: false },
    { id: 15, name: "user15", popStatus: false }
  ]
  // what was this for?
  // popStatus: false
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  function popIt(id) {
    setState((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        users: prev.users.map((user) =>
          user.id === id ? { ...user, popStatus: true } : user
        )
      };
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>List of users Records</h3>
      <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
        {state.users.map((user) => (
          <li key={user.id}>
            {user.name}{" "}
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => {
                popIt(user.id);
              }}
            >
              {user.name}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div className="main-area">
        {state.users.map(
          (user) =>
            user.popStatus && (
              <div key={user.id} className="contact-box">
                <b>Username:</b>
                {user.name}
                <br />
                Message .........
                <br />
                Message .........
              </div>
            )
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Screenshot of how user info is displayed in sequence no matter what order users are clicked:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your map function:

```
{this.state.arr.map((obj, i) => (
    <div  key={i} className="contact_box" >
        {obj.popStatus === true && <div className="">
           <b>Username:</b> {obj.name}<br />
```

First you print contact_box div, and later you check popStatus, and based on that you print content. Because you set CSS for the cotact_box, which is printed always, you have these blank spots.

Just move contact_box div inside if statement, and it should be fine:

```
{this.state.arr.map((obj, i) => (
   {obj.popStatus === true &&
       <div  key={i} className="contact_box" >
           <b>Username:</b> {obj.name}<br />
           // rest of the box
       </div>
   }
 )}
```

In the process, you can rid of this additional div.

Also, I recommend using functional component and hooks, it will be simpler to manage the state, and it is recommended for newer React versions.